# CHROME - EXTENSION: Rendered fewer hooks than expected

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am working on a project which creates a web extension. I am checking if my function returns different, I set the new value. Then, I am using the states in return function. However I am getting an error : **Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement.** How can I fix that?

```
 const [isSecure, setIsSecure] = useState<boolean>(true)
 const [isTabEmpty, setIsTabEmpty] = useState<boolean>(false)

 useEffect(() => {
    if (hostIsSecure() !== isSecure) {
      setIsSecure(hostIsSecure)
    }
    if (tabEmpty() !== isTabEmpty) {
      setIsTabEmpty(tabEmpty)
    }
  }, [host, tabEmpty, hostIsSecure])

  function hostIsSecure(): boolean {
    if (protocol && protocol === 'https:') {
      return true
    } else return false
  }

  function tabEmpty(): boolean {
    if (
      curTabId &&
      Object.keys(tabHosts).filter(
        (id) => curTabId.toString() === id.toString()
      ).length === 1
    )
      return false
    else return false
  }
```

Comment: Do you have any other calls to `useState`/`useEffect`/other hooks in the component?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova no

Comment: I don't see anything criminal, would you be able to make a reproducible example?

Comment: I dont understand what is that? you want I share full code ? @NadiaChibrikova

Comment: Adding more code might help, but if you could make a reproducible example in codepen or similar it'd be better (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova thank you I remove use effect and write functions inside useState directly, it works.